# Upload a txt file to jenkins build job as build parameter

Tags: jenkins

Need some help to know about uploading a test case file to Jenkins Build job as build parameter is it possible?

I am aware of following options

1. Parametric build where we can specify the source code path at run time
2. Copy files into the job's workspace before building

but both the options we have to give the path i am looking at option where we can upload files to Jenkins build job (similar to attaching files to email).

Is it possible?

Comment: 3. You can specify URL as build parameter and download from this URL before running the test case =)

Comment: Thanks for response; but looking at some much more user friendly option; like developers what to run some specific test cases not dependent on complete set of test cases available in Source code management; in this case developer can create his one test case file and instead of checking in to source code he can upload file to build job and trigger the build to see faster results..

Comment: Really hope you are not trying to reinvent the wheel here... Your developer may be better-off simply running the build from the command-line with whatever parameters he likes.

Comment: What's wrong with the file build parameter? It allows uploading file when starting the job. It will be uploaded to specific path, but if it is an archive, it can be extracted to produce anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no plugin for such a capability. I suggest you stick to your original idea of using the file parameter or write your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If looking for an interactive solution:

- Have a set of check-boxes as parameters, each representing a different test-case
- Let the developer check the required tests when running the build

If you plan to run this as an unattended job:

- Let the developer edit a parameters-file in a known location
  and specify the required tests in this parameters-file
- The build-job will read this parameters-file when it runs,
  and will act up-on it

Answer (score 0):

**Config File Provider Plugin** for Jenkins "Adds the ability to provide configuration files (i.e., settings.xml for maven, XML, groovy, custom files, etc.) loaded through the Jenkins UI which will be copied to the job's workspace."

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

In the Jenkins **Build Environment** section check option **Provide Configuration files**.

Then you can "Make globally configured files available in your local workspace. All files configured via the config-file-provider plugin are available and can be referenced."