# How to upload a generic file into a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to find a way to prompt the user to select and upload a generic file from a local machine to a Jenkins job prior to build. The input file that user is going to upload is not necessarily a text or a property file.

I am specifically trying to get the user to "select" their desired file - browse to their file ; the user should not pass the file's path.

Thanks

Comment: This might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914244/upload-a-txt-file-to-jenkins-build-job-as-build-parameter

Comment: Using `curl`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348480/how-to-upload-file-from-command-line-as-file-parameter-in-jenkins

Comment: What is the windows equivalent to curl?

Answer (score 42):

Use the **File Parameter**:

> File parameter allows a build to accept a file, to be submitted by the user when scheduling a new build. The file will be placed inside the workspace at the known location after the check-out/update is done, so that your build scripts can use this file.

[image]

If you need to verify the file has a certain extension, you would have to do that with a script as part of your job, and fail the job is extension/content-type does not match what you need.

Comment: This is fine if using a browser, but I would like to create a job using a local python script to a remote Jenkins, which has a File Parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of annoying to handle when you don't know what the file name will be or need to change its name before it reaches its destination. You kind of need to perform a hack. This is how I do it:

1. Use the "File parameter" parameter to upload your file
2. Use the OS-specific script to rename the file from whatever you named your `File Parameter` to whatever you want it to be, e.g., if my `File Parameter` had the `File location` value of `file_name` instead of an actual relative file-path, I'd then do something like this for say, Windows inside a Build-Step for "Execute Windows Batch Command":

`move .\file_name .\%file_name%`

And then just use ArtifactDeployer to copy everything there to your desired location.

ps: this won't remove digital signatures, so the move-operation should be considered mostly safe.

Answer (score 4):

The use of the Jenkins File Parameter will not work for Jenkins pipelines.  It's ridiculous that they don't disable that kind of build parameter for pipelines.  It's even more ridiculous that they don't at the very least, identify this SEVERE limitation in the help documentation for that parameter.

It would have saved me a couple hours trying to figure out why it would not work in my pipeline.

Refer to this feature request for more details: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413

Comment: Late to read this comment, I wasted hours figuring out how to upload and use a file :(

Comment: @elulcao Did you ever figure out a way?  I am submitting jobs using a browser, but I would like to submit a job using a python script, however one of the parameters is a file parameter.

Comment: @RufusVS No, I couldn't do anything to upload a file. So, I just WA the problem by cloning the file from a temporary repository. Something like clicking a button and then point to the repo branch. The thing is that user should upload a file to that repo. :(

Comment: @elulcao I saw other suggestions while googling about using curl, which I rejected because I was using Windows, not Linux, but then I found out Windows 10 came with curl, so I will be looking into that..