# Add file to Jenkins workspace without plugins

Tags: jenkins, workspace

I need to add custom file to Jenkins job workspace, but I have no opportunity to add any kind of plugins. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `File Parameter`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491789/how-to-upload-a-generic-file-into-a-jenkins-job

Comment: @WillWebb no, I haven't try that. But i Don't want to upload file each time I'm running the job. I need to upload it only once and then it should be stored there.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context. Where is the file? Can you get it using curl? Is it on the host, or any of the slaves (you might be able to use `stash`/`unstash` then)?

Comment: @neckobik if you do not clean the workspace it persists (depending on the type of job), however if you allow concurrency, jenkins might create a second workspace, where of course the file is not present. Best is to just add it to you version control, so it will be checked out each time

Comment: I'v found the solution, thank you for your time.

Comment: @neckobik Maybe you can share it as an answer, so other people might be helped if they run into the same problem

Comment: @neckobik Requesting you to please share the answer... I have a similar requirement.