# How to run maven test class based on conditions from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am using POM in automation and in the test I have 3 classes. let's say `test1, test2 and test3`

tester is providing a class name in property file so if tester provide like `test1` in a property file, I have put conditions in java code to run class based on what tester provide in property file.

But now I want to set up the same thing from Jenkins using a single build. I do not want to create 3 builds for 3 classes,  So if in property file tester provide value `test1`, it should run class `test1` from jenkins.

I did check for conditional build steps but seems could not satisfy my need.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `includeFile` property of the Maven surefire plugin, you can explicitly say which Test classes should be run. You can provide this file from the command line (e.g. in Jenkins) by using an expression like `-Dsurefire.includesFile={yourfile}`.

Comment: Here I want to tell that if property file's x field  = **test1** then include **test1**, and execute it.  can you please give more detail on same?  I mean I need to include test but conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as before and let the tester provide the test class names in a file. That file is either already available on your system, or it can be uploaded by the tester when the Jenkins job builds. For that you have to parameterize the Jenkins job, and define a file upload parameter. See [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=34930782#content/view/34930782) for a start point, and these two Stackoverflow questions: [How to upload a generic file into a Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491789/how-to-upload-a-generic-file-into-a-jenkins-job) and [How to use file parameter in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224691/how-to-use-file-parameter-in-jenkins/42242113)

Now, this file upload is tedious for the testers. Why not change the job parameter to a input field respectively a text field, and provide at job build the tests class names as comma separated string respectively multi line text?

Comment: Yes so it is easy to set up job parameter as input and provides classnames as comma separate but I have 3 class and want to execute only 1 based on what tester has provided into property file. Yes, property file is there in workspace.

Comment: Hmmm, what’s then the problem? Either use your previous solution, which worked as far as I understand, or the solution from @“JF Meier”, which is the way to go, in my opinion (the official Maven way). Or did I misunderstand the question/issue?