# How to run CI selenium side runner tests on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-ide

I have a .side file generated by the **Selenium IDE**, which I need to run on **CI** using **Jenkins**.

I am running it as a build step with the following shell command:

```
selenium-side-runner /path/to/file.ide
```

The problem arises due to the fact that no matter if the selenium test fails, Jenkins always shows is as success.

In this thread it's suggested to upload the file as generic, but still, the commands to execute it are missing
[How to upload a generic file into a Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491789/how-to-upload-a-generic-file-into-a-jenkins-job)

I've found a possible solution to it on this posts, but I would appreciate having a cleaner way to solve this instead of parsing the results checking for errors.
[How to mark a build unstable in Jenkins when running shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148122/how-to-mark-a-build-unstable-in-jenkins-when-running-shell-scripts)

Is there a plugin able to run selenium .side files on Jenkins and this one showing the success/failures of the test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate a Junit test report file and then use the Jenkins Junit plugin after your tests execution.

```
selenium-side-runner --output-directory=results --output-format=junit
# Outputs results in `junit` frormat in `./results/projectName.xml'
```

Check the [official documentation](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/#output-test-results-to-a-file) for more details.