# Upload large(mb) files from jenkins GUI to respective build workspace

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a scenario where i need to upload large (mb’s) file from Jenkins GUI to workspace?

Is there a way to achieve this request?

Please let me know the available solutions.

File should get uploaded to workspace.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to search first, the solution was easy to find: Seems you can use a file parameter like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508220/3623345)

Answer (score 0):

To upload large files from the Jenkins GUI to the respective build workspace, you can use the "File Parameter" feature in Jenkins. That feature allows users to upload a file through the Jenkins GUI, which can then be accessed by the build job in its workspace.

```bash
┌────────────────┐     ┌─────────────┐     ┌────────────────────────────────┐
│ Jenkins Server │ ──> │ Jenkins GUI │ ──> │ File Upload via File Parameter │
└────────────────┘     └─────────────┘     └────────────────────────────────┘
       │                                           │
       V                                           V
┌────────────────┐                     ┌──────────────────────────────┐
│ Build Workspace│ ◄────────────────── │ File copied to workspace     │
│                │   during build      │ during build (using script)  │
└────────────────┘                     └──────────────────────────────┘
```

- Go to your Jenkins job configuration page.
- Under "General" section, check "That project is parameterized".
- Add a new parameter of type "File Parameter".
- Enter a name for the file parameter (e.g., `UPLOAD_FILE`).

In your build script (like a shell script), refer to the uploaded file by the parameter name. For a pipeline job, you can use it directly in your script.

```bash
# Shell Script Example
# Access the uploaded file using the parameter name
cp $UPLOAD_FILE ${WORKSPACE}/desired-subfolder/
```

```
// Pipeline Script Example
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        file(name: 'UPLOAD_FILE')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Upload File') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Copy the file to the workspace
                    sh "cp \$UPLOAD_FILE \${WORKSPACE}/desired-subfolder/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You might want to try the ["Jenkins File Parameter plugin"](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/)

> Offers alternative types of file parameter that are compatible with Pipeline and do not suffer from the architectural flaws of the type built into Jenkins core.

Using the File Parameter plugin, your Jenkins pipeline script would look slightly different to handle file uploads:

For a base64 file parameter:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        base64File 'FILE'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Upload File') {
            steps {
                withFileParameter('FILE') {
                    // Use the file here, for example, copying it to a desired location
                    sh 'cp $FILE ${WORKSPACE}/desired-subfolder/'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a [stashed](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) file parameter:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        stashedFile 'FILE'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Upload File') {
            steps {
                unstash 'FILE'
                // Use the file here, for example, moving it to keep the original filename
                sh 'mv FILE ${WORKSPACE}/desired-subfolder/$FILE_FILENAME'
            }
        }
    }
}
```